# Codelite isn´t responding when I run it after build

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codelite

I am using Codelite for the first time. I can successfully build code, but Codelite remains unresponsive to the Run command (or to ctrl+F5). Below is the screenshot of the build log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spvmi.jpg)

What could possibly be the cause of this issue? i can´t find any documentation on the subject.

Codelite version : 11.0.8

Best regards,
Chetan

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl` Do you have all of the required libraries installed?

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you checked your window manager keyboard shortcuts? Probably they conflict with your IDE setting.